# Facebook Comment Listener returns Comment's box ID instead of comment's ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using a listener to get comments ID in the Facebook Social Comments Plugin.

```
    // Additional initialization code here, this is where we listen to events
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
      function(response) {
        alert('You commented in URL: ' + response.href + 'CommentID: ' + response.commentID);
        // do an ajax call to server to store user,commentID,href info if you require
      }
    );
  };
```

My problem is that the returned ID is the comments box ID and I want the comment's ID. How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug regarding this.

It can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457493477614026?browse=search_50117b894df0d6925218896).

It seems it has been assigned, so you can expect a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

the ID you got is the object id of the comment box

you can query for its comments using fql,  for example:

`SELECT text,post_fbid,username,fromid,time FROM comment WHERE object_id=10150692213226360`

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3Dselect%20text%2Cpost_fbid%2Cfromid%2Ctime%20from%20comment%20where%20object_id%3D10150692213226360

for more information about the comment table in the fql you can browse:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/